# How to calculate azure elastic pool storage utilization?

Tags: database, azure, storage, azure-elasticpool

I've an Azure elastic pool (Standard, 300 eDTU ) with 105 databases.
According to the azure dashboard I've a storage Utilization of 195.92 GB and a Storage capacity of 400 GB. While adding data to a database I got an error message "The elastic pool has reached its storage limit. The storage usage for the elastic pool cannot exceed (409600) MBs."

How can I calculated the actual size of all the databases? Can the difference between actual and used storage be more than 50%?

Comment: I am looking into this but can you detail if you are taking multiple backups or are you deleting a bunch of data periodically? A quick fix might be to reclaim some space by using the DBCC SHRINKDATABASE command on targeted database(s) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-file-space-management#reclaim-unused-allocated-space

Comment: In looking through this, you options are to scale up to a larger data tier and leave it at that or, run the following T-SQL on master database: SELECT * FROM sys.elastic_pool_resource_stats   
ORDER BY end_time DESC; FOLLOWED BY DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (N'db_name') on those databases where the following metrics indicate from the first query indicate there is possible space to reclaim: elastic_pool_storage_limit_mb
max_xtp_storage_percent
avg_allocated_storage_percent

Answer (score 1):

The max storage per database in your Azure elastic poor(Standard, 300 eDTU ) is `1024 Gb`.
[image]

When you adding data to a database, you get the error: "The elastic pool has reached its storage limit. The storage usage for the elastic pool cannot exceed (409600) MBs."

Here's a  bob has the same error with you, maybe you can read it as a reference:[The elastic pool has reached its storage limit. The storage usage for the elastic pool cannot exceed (204800)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52496146/azure-sql-server-error-the-elastic-pool-has-reached-its-storage-limit-the-sto).

Hope it helps you.